# Understanding a Unix line

Tags: unix

everybody! I have a simple question.
What does this line do?

```
trap "exec 1>&6 6>&- ; cat $LOGFILE" 0
```

So far, I understand that I am moving the standard output to 6 (this variable hasn't been declared before, so I assume that 6 is a variable created in this same line), then the '6>&-' is something I don't really get... and the cat $LOGFILE shows the contents of the variable LOGFILE. Also, the 0 at the end is supposed to mean that at the end of the execution of my program, execute 'exec 1>&6 6>&- ; cat $LOGFILE' before exiting.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17784.html for more details on this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `trap <command> 0` means to execute `<command>` upon exit of the shell
2. `exec 1>&6` means to redirect STDOUT (fd1) to fd6
3. `exec 6>&-` means to close fd6

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing: the fd6 wasn't declared before that line... Does that mean that fd6 is instantly created in this same line?